# Qt Creator - Getting error D8021 - Invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I'm using Qt creator to make a very simple GUI. It was functioning properly for the past couple weeks, I'm honestly not sure what I changed but I'll do my best to detail what it could be.

Windows 10
Qt Creator 5.5

Currently using the following lines in the .pro file, but commenting them out makes no difference:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra
CONFIG += c++14
```

I am guessing it either has to do with some odd flag/exception, or the compiler I'm using. In all honesty, I can't tell what compiler I'm using, but I can tell you that in the compiler options in settings, it has 4 "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0"s under auto-detected.

I'm really not sure what to do here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know how to solve this one, but those flags will definitely not work with Visual Studio's compiler. Did your project formerly use mingw or another compiler with GCC-style arguments? Did you install Visual Studio lately?

Comment: I haven't touched anything related to the compiler. Whatever the default is, it was that. And no, I have had Visual Studio for a while before installing this.

Comment: Weird. Well, the problem is it's trying to use GCC compiler options with Visual Studio. Why? This I can't say. Also I know nothing about QT creator, but there must be a way to set the compiler to be used by a project. Internet says it should be at `Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers`. I recommend a look there to see what compilers you can use. For Windows you most likely have mingw (with a slimmer possibility of clang) installed.

Comment: `-Wextra` is for gcc. VS has a `-W`,  but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: With `MinGW`, the error is dispeared